# NSWindow ignoring position set

Tags: swift, xcode, nswindow

I'm not sure if it's a glitch or I'm doing something wrong, but for some reason the window's position on the screen becomes problematic if I disable this option:

[image]

When I first disable the option, running the program a couple of times while changing the position of the window (either via code or inspector) works normally, then it suddenly won't respond to any more changes of position from the inspector:

[image]

not even from the AppDelegate.swift code:

[image]

It just simply gets stuck at where it was when it ran at that session, ignoring any future changes to the position set in the code or the Size Inspector until I enable Visible At Launch again.

The reason why I'm making the window invisible and then making it visible again is because on launch, I'm setting some attributes (such as opaqueness and background colour which I removed from the code) where without making the window invisible in the first place, the default window will appear for a split second before all the settings have been made in code and then the window will appear in the right place with the right colour and etc.

Am I doing anything wrong? Was there something I forgot to initialise? Or should I just report this as a bug to Apple?

Answer (score 2):

You should alter window settings in `awakeFromNib()` and `windowDidLoad()` of the NSWindowController class associated with your NSWindow instance. Then there is no need to mess with the visibility of your window, because the window will be visible *after* these methods.